# MalformedURLException Java get XML from Server

Tags: java, xml

I have following problem:

```
try {
        String uri = "http://servername/ReportServer?%2fCool%Page&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=XML&mandantId=2000";
        URL url = new URL(uri);

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer xform = tFactory.newTransformer();

        xform.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(System.out));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now I get

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: servername/ReportServer?%2fCool%Page&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=XML&mandantId=2000
```

I want to get the **xml content in java**. If I type the url into the browser I get the xml as a download. I don't know why I get this error. Someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Most likely your browser adds the protocol ("http", or "https") automatically. Also, I don't think the URI you provided is actually resolvable (not only the protocol is missing but also no top level domain is given).

Comment: Now i have added "http" to the URL-String. Now he doesnt throw an exception but also he is doing nothing. Why he doesn't system.out the content?

Comment: And the URL is working in the browser! I actually changed the names but it works fine in the browser and i get my xml-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You forgot to define the protocol in your URL.**

> Protocol handlers for the following protocols are guaranteed to exist
>   on the search path :-
>
> ```
>  http, https, ftp, file, and jar
> ```

From Java API documentation for URL :
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html

> ```
> public URL(String spec)
>     throws MalformedURLException
> ```
>
> Creates a URL object from the String representation. This constructor
>   is equivalent to a call to the two-argument constructor with a null
>   first argument.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - *spec* - the String to parse as a URL.
>
> **Throws:**
>
> - *MalformedURLException* - if no protocol is specified, or an unknown protocol is found, or spec is null.

You should have something like (example with HTTP) :

```
String uri = "http://servername/ReportServer?%2fCool%Page&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=XML&mandantId=2000";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have added it already. Now the error is gone but i don't get my xml file. Theres no output.

Comment: Thank you, you were right. Now i got problems with the docbuilder but i can do the rest. Thanks for your help!